# Celery tasks don't run in docker container

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

In Django, I want to perform a Celery task (let's say add 2 numbers) when a user uploads a new file in `/media`. What I've done is to use `signals` so when the associated Upload object is saved the celery task will be fired.

Here's my code and Docker configuration:

`signals.py`

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from core.models import Upload
from core.tasks import add_me

def upload_save(sender, instance, signal, *args, **kwargs):
    print("IN UPLOAD SIGNAL") # <----- LOGS PRINT UP TO HERE, IN CONTAINERS
    add_me.delay(10)    

post_save.connect(upload_save, sender=Upload) # My post save signal
```

`tasks.py`

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task(ignore_result=True, max_retries=3)    
def add_me(upload_id):
    print('In celery') # <----- This is not printed when in Docker!
    return upload_id + 20
```

`views.py`

```
class UploadView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = UploadSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UploadSerializer(data=request.data)
        print("SECOND AFTER")
        print(request.data) <------ I can see my file name here
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print("THIRD AFTER") <------ This is printer OK in all cases
            serializer.save()
            print("FOURTH AFTER") <----- But this is not printed when in Docker!
            return response.Response(
                {"Message": "Your file was  uploaded"},
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
            )

        return response.Response(
            {"Message": "Failure", "Errors": serializer.errors},
            status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
        )
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    # build: ./database_docker/
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db
      POSTGRES_USER: test_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test_pass
    # volumes:
    #   - media:/code/media

  web:
    build: ./docker/
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate --noinput && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - media:/code/media
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.6.10
    volumes:
      - media:/code/media

  worker:
    build: ./docker/
    command: celery -A example_worker worker --loglevel=debug -n worker1.%h
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - media:/code/media
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
volumes:
  media:
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:latest
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code
```

Everything works OK when not in Docker.

The problem is that when I'm deploying the above in Docker and try to upload a file, the request never finishes even-though the file is uploaded in the `media` folder (confirmed it by accessing its contents in both the `web` and `worker` containers).

More specifically it seems that the Celery task is not executed (finished?) and the code after the `serializer.save()` is never reached.

When I remove the signal (thus no Celery task is fired) everything is OK. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score -2):

I just figured it out. Turns out that I need to add the following in the `__init__.py` of my application.

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ("celery_app",)
```

Don't know why everything is running smoothly without this piece of code when I'm not using containers...